# Can i use the latest jquery click event

Tags: jquery

Currently I have used the *jquery.js*

Now i have updated the latest jquery.1.11.1.js

I will updated the plugin to click events not working.

Do I have to make any change the click event based in latest jquery?

Comment: Latest Jquery version is 3.2.x

Comment: Oh! i forgot to mention it.

Comment: jquery.mobile.1.4.5.js can i change the click event?

Answer (score 3):

The latest jQuery version is jQuery 3.2.1 you can get it from here [link](http://jquery.com/download/)

and here is a example of a click event on jQuery 3.2.1

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").click(function(){
        alert("The paragraph was clicked.");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click on this paragraph.</p>
```

And here is a example of click on 1.10.2.js

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>click demo</title>
  <style>
  p {
    color: red;
    margin: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  p:hover {
    background: yellow;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<p>First Paragraph</p>
<p>Second Paragraph</p>
<p>Yet one more Paragraph</p>
 
<script>
$( "p" ).click(function() {
  $( this ).slideUp();
});
</script>
```

So you don't have to change your click event if you are using latest version.

PS. I am also not sure what you are asking, I provided a answer from what I could make out of your question.

Comment: Can i use the $('#id"').on('click', function (){ } in jquery-1.11.1.min.js